# updating ubuntu!

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I didn't receive the upgrade notification on the upgrade manager, so I clicked "search for upgrades" but the new 12.04 didn't appear. Can anyone tell me how to manually upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10? Thank you very much

Comment: Hm..., has the update manager been renamed? Anyway, try running `update-manager -d` in a terminal.

Comment: Where did you click "search for upgrades"?  Anyway, did you use the "official" instructions at [Upgrade Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade)?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to ***upgrade*** using a **LIVE CD/USB**

Its safer and less error prone.

There are many reasons and factors affection it as to why *online update* may cause problems such as the Internet speed,stability of your current version,etc.

So while i would suggest an upgrade using **LIVE CD/USB** you may still opt for the *online update* if you wish.

But i would like to specify that aready your computer is *not* showing up the 12.04 *upgrade*. Be carefull to decide whether to opt for *online upgrade*.

For any help on how to upgrade using a **LIVE CD/USB** leave a comment.